# Writing to a file printing blank file

Tags: java, file-io, binary-tree, printwriter

The program I have is currently a binary tree composed of two types of nodes: Questions and Answers.

After the tree has been filled I am trying to print out the structure of the tree using a preorder traversal of the tree. My current code is this:

```
private static void writeToFile(LinkedBinaryTreeNode<String> node){
    try {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
        node.traversePreorder( n -> {

            if( n.isLeaf() ){
                writer.println("A: " + n.getData());
            } else {
                writer.println("Q: " + n.getData());
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Whenever I run the program and create a full tree and try to output the structure to a file I simply get a blank file.

**I know the logic is correct since placing:**

```
System.out.println("A: " + n.getData());
```

**and:**

```
System.out.println("Q: " + n.getData());
```

in their respective locations replacing the printwriter, produces the correct output to the console.

Comment: More precisely, do you ever `flush()` your `Writer`? (In some cases `close()` internally invokes `flush()`).

Comment: No, I forgot to do that. Would that be placed in the try block or would that have to be placed in a finally clause at the end?

Comment: `flush()` goes into `try` and `close()` goes into `finally`. Note that you can also use [`try-with-resources`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html), but you definitly have to `flush` it.

Answer (score 0):

**Close the writer as follow:**

```
private static void writeToFile(LinkedBinaryTreeNode<String> node){
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
        node.traversePreorder( n -> {

            if( n.isLeaf() ){
                writer.println("A: " + n.getData());
            } else {
                writer.println("Q: " + n.getData());
            }
        });
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```